# Python update Dataframe with another Dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

How do I update one pandas dataframe with another dataframe (update the old data  columns from master table  and add new data from update table )

```
import pandas as pd

master_tb = {
'Id' : ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7'],
'dt_id' : [20230130,20230104,20230130,20230130,20230130,20230130,20230130],
'A' : [0,3,4,2,9,8,7],
'B' : [5,8,3,1,6,4,2],
'C' : [5,2,6,8,8,8,7] }

updt_tb = {
'cal_Id' : [20230103,20230215,20230104,20230104,20230504],
'org_id' : ['A2','A2','A5','A9','A5'],
'A' : [30,80,100,100,80],
'B' : [0,10,90,40,40],
'R' : [0,100,50,60,80],
'C' : [30,10,50,40,80],
'T' : [90,50,50,40,30]  }

# creating a Dataframe object 
df_master = pd.DataFrame(master_tb)
df_updt = pd.DataFrame(updt_tb)
```

Update columns A,B,C in df_master from matching records in df_updt

A logical  query would be -
update master dataFrame
join:
df_master.Id= df_updt.org_id

Conditions: where
df_master.Id = df_updt.org_id ( id's match )
AND
df_master.dt_id < df_updt.cal_id  ( updt table date is greater than the master table date for matched  record)

Tried isin() method but was a failure ,

```
Id  dt_id       A   B   C
A1  20230130    0   5   5
A2  20230104    80  10  10
A3  20230130    4   3   6
A4  20230130    2   1   8
A5  20230130    80  40  80 
A6  20230130    8   4   8
A7  20230130    7   2   7
```

**Sample output data**

in the above example A2 and A5 are two recored from updt table.
-- A2 has two records in updt and only one date which is greater than the record date in master

-- A5 has two dates in updt  which are  greater than the date in Master ,
in that case , the most recent one should be picked up

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [janitor](/questions/tagged/janitor) to get the *matches*, then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) your master `df` :

```
# pip install pyjanitor
# pandas<2.0.3
import janitor

cols_to_upd = ["A", "B", "C"]

matches = (
    df_master.conditional_join(
        df_updt,
        ("Id", "org_id", "=="),
        ("dt_id", "cal_Id", "<")
    ).xs("right", axis=1).set_index("org_id")
     # [cols_to_upd] optional since `update` aligns the indices/cols
)

tmp = df_master.set_index("Id") ; tmp.update(matches)

out = tmp.reset_index().convert_dtypes()
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Id     dt_id   A   B   C
0  A1  20230130   0   5   5
1  A2  20230104  80  10  10
2  A3  20230130   4   3   6
3  A4  20230130   2   1   8
4  A5  20230130  80  40  80
5  A6  20230130   8   4   8
6  A7  20230130   7   2   7
```

Comment: Thanks Timeless ,Your answer works well .
 Is there any chance we could do away with cols_to_upd
Thanks Again

Comment: You're welcome. Using `cols_to_upd` is optional but if you still want to, you can uncomment the last chain in `matches`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_master.reset_index().sort_values('dt_id'),
                   df_updt.sort_values('cal_Id'), 
                   left_by='Id', 
                   right_by='org_id',  
                   left_on='dt_id', 
                   right_on='cal_Id',
                   direction='forward',
                   allow_exact_matches=False).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
print (df)
   Id     dt_id  A_x  B_x  C_x      cal_Id org_id   A_y   B_y      R   C_y  \
1  A2  20230104    3    8    2  20230215.0     A2  80.0  10.0  100.0  10.0   
0  A1  20230130    0    5    5         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   
2  A3  20230130    4    3    6         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   
3  A4  20230130    2    1    8         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   
4  A5  20230130    9    6    8  20230504.0     A5  80.0  40.0   80.0  80.0   
5  A6  20230130    8    4    8         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   
6  A7  20230130    7    2    7         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   

      T  
1  50.0  
0   NaN  
2   NaN  
3   NaN  
4  30.0  
5   NaN  
6   NaN
```

---

```
out = (df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace('_y',''), axis=1)
         .combine_first(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace('_x',''), axis=1))
         .reindex(df_master.columns, axis=1)
         .astype(df_master.dtypes)
         .sort_index()
            )
print (out)
   Id     dt_id   A   B   C
0  A1  20230130   0   5   5
1  A2  20230104  80  10  10
2  A3  20230130   4   3   6
3  A4  20230130   2   1   8
4  A5  20230130  80  40  80
5  A6  20230130   8   4   8
6  A7  20230130   7   2   7
```